# ElasticSearch datatype Keyword make it searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-6

I have data and and i want to create index and want it to make searchable and aggregatable both.If I use datatype keyword I can't search any string but can aggregate but if I use datatype text then I can't aggregate but can search any string.
So please tell me how to resolve this problem. I am using elasticsearch 6

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to create a `text` field with a `keyword` sub-field so that you can do both, search text and aggregate values:

Your field mapping should look like this:

```
{
    "my_field": {
       "type": "text",
       "fields": {
           "keyword": {
               "type": "keyword"
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Using the above mapping, you can search on the `my_field` field and aggregate and `my_field.keyword`.

Comment: Any other way to do some custom tokenizer or something ?

Comment: It's not clear what your use case is. Feel free to describe it in more details with examples.