# ElasticSearch Keyword usage

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the following mapping which used the default analyzer in a 5.1 environment:

```
{
    "description": {
        "type": "text"
    },
    "keywords": {
        "type": "keyword"
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "text"
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the [keywords](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) field to do a text based search, however unless I search on the full exact phrase that is stored in the field I get no results back.

I've tried using the [Common Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html) search and there was no improvement.

I can do a simple match query on the title or description fields and get results back for one or more of the values in the search.  What would be keeping me from using the keyword field to search for any items that contains one or more words that are in the query?

Ultimately I'm trying to match on any item that contains one or more of the words listed in the search and rank them from high to low based off of how many of the search terms an item contains in addition to how close the item's keywords value matches the full phrase.  I.e does it have more than one matching keyword and if so to they match the order or is there other characters between them and does it match the order of the searched value.

Comment: As described in the documentation you linked at, `keyword` fields are not indexed and hence only searchable by their exact value. If you want to do a text based search, you need to change to `text` type or [do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51532085/4604579)

Comment: I skipped right over that sentence, thank you.  What gives using a keyword field more value than just a text field?  Especially if you could do an exact match on a text field which in IMO accomplishes the same result.

Comment: Both have their specific usage. text fields are meant for full text search and analysis. keyword fields are more suited when you need to aggregate, sort and filter on exact values.

Comment: @Val can the mapping for the keyword column be updated to include it in the index so it is searchable?

Comment: Do you mean can the keyword field also be text? Yes, you can and you'll need to call `_update_by_query` on your index in order to update the inverted index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51532085/4604579

Comment: @Val I meant can I up the existing mapping for the keyword field’s index property and set it to true?

Comment: The `index` property is true by default: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html